# How to find 100 GB of most recently modified files and send to rsync for local synchronization

Tags: shell, rsync, sort

I need to select 100gig of most recently changed files from a local directory and do an `rsync` to a local directory (skipping files that are already rsynced).

If I try something like

```
find . -mtime +3 -type f -print0 | rsync -0v --files-from=- ~/source ~/destination
```

I only pick up most recently modified files, not adding up to 100gig -- or it may be > than 100gig in the +3 range.

I tried

```
du -ak /volume1/surveillance/* | sort -k1n | awk '
(size += $1) > 1*1024*1024 {quit}
{print substr($0, index(s, "\t")+1)}'
```

But this will only pick the top 1gig (in this case) based on file size sort order, i.e. it ignores the created date of each file.

Any ideas?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. In this case `rsync` won't use its incremental/delta algorithm for a local copy, so it's directly equivalent to `cp`. Does it matter to you that files "beyond" the 100GB limit may not ever get copied?

Comment: So instead of `du -ak` use `ls -ltak`, and instead of `awk '... {print substr()...}'` use `print $9`. Does that work for you?

Comment: `ls -ltaks /volume1/surveillance/* | sort -k1n | awk ' (size += $1) > 1*1024*1024 {quit} {print $9}'` kind of thing

Comment: Thanks, when I run 

`ls -ltaksRh /v/s/* | grep \.mp4$ | sort -k1n | awk '
 (size += $1) > 1*1024*1024 {quit} 
 {print $6 "\t" $7 " " $8 " "$9 "\t" $10} 
' ` 

(I added $6..$10    for testing, I get the sort ascending by file size, I need this to be by date..up to 100gig max)

The target directory must contain the 100gig most recent mp4 files (from CCTV). (I then copy that to cloud). If I use `rsync`, then I would get for 'free' the deletion of older files in the target directory If I do `cp` I will need a separate script to delete in the target directory the older files.

Comment: I forgot - don't sort. Put the output of `ls` directly to the `awk` adder.